# How to call a particular method every some seconds in c#?

Tags: c#, timer, facebook-c#-sdk

"Robot Game" is the first basic game I developed. The Magenta '#' character is an enemy and it is supposed have a random movement in this map, but its random movement is too fast and I tried to use Threading but it effects all characters' speed. Now, I need To call the "Enemy" method every 100 milliseconds.

Robot game Image:
[image]

Comment: Use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.timers.timer.aspx). Here's a basic [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer).

Comment: Have you tried this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954859/run-function-every-second-visual-c-sharp

Comment: or this so question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897787/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-call-a-method-every-20-seconds?rq=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [System.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx). However, be forewarned that these timers might not be as accurate as you may desire. You'll never easily get a fully-accurate timer on a non-realtime OS such as Windows, but if you want better timer accuracy, a [Multimedia timer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework) might help.

System.Timer example from MSDN:

```
public class Timer1
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Normally, the timer is declared at the class level, 
        // so that it stays in scope as long as it is needed. 
        // If the timer is declared in a long-running method,   
        // KeepAlive must be used to prevent the JIT compiler  
        // from allowing aggressive garbage collection to occur  
        // before the method ends. You can experiment with this 
        // by commenting out the class-level declaration and  
        // uncommenting the declaration below; then uncomment 
        // the GC.KeepAlive(aTimer) at the end of the method. 
        //System.Timers.Timer aTimer; 

        // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program.");
        Console.ReadLine();

        // If the timer is declared in a long-running method, use 
        // KeepAlive to prevent garbage collection from occurring 
        // before the method ends. 
        //GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }

    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is  
    // raised. 
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you might have forgotten the autoreset = true? Am I wrong here?

Comment: @Gaspa79 Timer.AutoReset defaults to true https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yup, you're right. It didn't work for me at first because I was using a different Timer. Thanks =)

Comment: I have been able to get a fairly accurate regular execution from threads on Windows, but this was in C++. I set up a thread to run every so many milliseconds to produce morse code once and it appeared to be regularly timed down to the millisecond. But Chrome was installed, which upped the timer resolution. You can run commands to up the timer resolution on Windows I believe, but not sure if this is possible in C#.