# Repeating an even every second in a DLL (C#)

Tags: c#, dll, timing

So I am writing (or more specifically adding) to a dll file so that it can call a function every second, the function will be to send some data over to a file which can then be  read by another program.
The problem I have is that I haven't been able to find any timing systems that don't involve a form or console application, I just want this is to happen in the  without any GUI, (or any UI at all!)
I've looked into system.timers.timer but form what I can tell that needs a console and.
Is this possible? and if so how?
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: How are the functions represented in this library going to be activated? Is this dll going to be used within an executable that is run manually or scheduled as part of a service hosted in a scheduler such as Windows Services or similar?

Comment: Why do you think that System.Timers.Timer (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/393k7sb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) requires a Console?

Comment: I am using a music player called MusicBee which allows for DLL plugins, the DLL file has to parts: one that grabs data from the MusicBee API and one for a server (so that I can see the data in a webpage) Basically it all needs to be handled internally as the activation flags included in the API don't do what I need. I was thinking of using an infinite while loop with a sleep call of 500 in there. Would that work?

Comment: "Why do you think that System.Timers.Timer ...requires a Console?" because they use this : "Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program at any time... ");
        Console.ReadLine();" and everything I've tried to use this w/out the console doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a GUI if this is simply intended to be a background application. It all depends upon how it is being hosted (see my comment on your original post about quiet exe vs service).

Here's a basic tutorial that may be of use: http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

Also note this previous question, which is very similar: [How to call a particular method every some seconds in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925844/how-to-call-a-particular-method-every-some-seconds-in-c)

As Dmitriy also suggested while I was typing this, I would advise running this on a background thread since it sounds like there is some processing necessary to generate the file. Your main code should simply establish the program and then launch a new thread to do the work every second (1000 milliseconds).

Information on that class is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

The MSDN page contains a solid example of how to use the class. In the example, a method called StatusChecker.CheckStatus does the background work. That function is specified with the line:

```
TimerCallback tcb = statusChecker.CheckStatus;
```

The line two after that one starts the timer and indicates that the callback should be raised after 1 second and every 1/4 second after that:

```
Timer stateTimer = new Timer(tcb, autoEvent, 1000, 250);
```

With the documentation provided there and this example you should be able to determine how to make the necessary modifications.

Comment: Thank you very much :-) I didn't want to use a GUI anyways so this is perfect. That microsoft link seems really useful, I'll look into it, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

What will load this dll - if a windows service; you can initiate a timer object in the service.start event; and then put your recurring function in timer.event.  Here is some pseudo code to get you started with:

Declare this globally:

```
System.Timers.Timer tmrMain = new System.Timers.Timer();
```

Then in the main() function set an interval - frequency at which you want your functions to be called:

```
tmrMain.Interval = 20000; //in milliseconds
tmrMain.Start();
```

And you should also declare an event handler:

```
private void tmrMain_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
//Your call to do something, every time this gets triggered at value specified in tmrMain.Interval
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you :-) I am using a media player called MusicBee and you can add DLL plugins to it, so I would presume it would be MusicBee that launches the DLL. I was thinking of putting it in a infinite while loop with a sleep call in to break it up, do you think this would work?