# How to auto update chart's X-axis every 5 sec?

Tags: c#, charts, timer

I am quite new to using the chart coding.But i manage to display chart on a click of the button. And 2nd click will change the "x-axis" as i set it as time.

Is there a way to auto update every 5 for the "X-axis" ?? As i know timer is needed to set the interval timing.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
    this.Time.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
}

private void GetData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sqlite_con1.Open();
    try
    {
        sqlite_cmd = sqlite_con1.CreateCommand();
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Temperature where id=12";
        sqlite_reader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();             
        while (sqlite_reader.Read()) 
        {
           this.chart1.Series["SAT"].Points.AddXY(Time.Text, sqlite_reader["Temp"]);      
        }
    }  
    catch (Exception ex)
    {   
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
    }
    sqlite_con1.Close();
 }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a particular method every some seconds in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925844/how-to-call-a-particular-method-every-some-seconds-in-c)

Comment: *Don't* put your charting code in the event handler. Put it on a separate method and call it from both the timer and click event handlers

Comment: PS: putting `timer1.Start()` *inside* the tick event is pointless. The event won't be raised unless the timer starts. Remove it from there and put it in an appropriate place, eg in a Start click event or the form's load event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set timer time and sets its property and event handler into timer at specific time

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 5000; // for five second interval
timer1.Enabled = true;
timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
```

and then you have to call you chart binding method in

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   timer1.Start();
   this.Time.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
   //here --- which you are calling on GetData_Click event by making  
   //separate method and call it here also
}
```